# $this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest() Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework

I am working on ZEND Framework that is new to me and same is the case with the AJAX. I tried lots of example but non of them work.

Please tell me I am wrong in this code.

**home.phtml**

```
<select name="year" onchange="saveChanges(this);">
                                    <option value="najam">Najam</option>
                                    <option value="Ali">Ali</option>
                                    <option value="Hassan">Hassan</option>
                                    <option value="Hassam">Hassam</option>

                                </select>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function saveChanges(object){   
    $.ajax({
        method :'POST',
        url: 'home',
        data: object.value,
        cache: false,
        error: function(e){
            alert(e);
            console.log("error" + e);
        },
        success: function(response){
            // A response to say if it's updated or not
            alert("Success" + object.value);
            console.log("Success");
        }
    });   
}
                                </script>
```

**HomeAction**

```
if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
//do this
}
else {
//do this
// It always in the else Part.
```

}

Although it print success message on console and also on the javascript alert message.

Help me if am wrong with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
method :'POST'
```

to

```
type: "POST"
```

I always use `$this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()` to detect a ajax request and always working.

*Sorry i speak English not well*

Update:

Controller:

```
final class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    final public function indexAction(){
        if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
            header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
            exit(json_encode(($this->_request->getPost())));
        }
    }      
}
```

View:

```
                            <select id="year" name="year">
                                <option value="najam">Najam</option>
                                <option value="Ali">Ali</option>
                                <option value="Hassan">Hassan</option>
                                <option value="Hassam">Hassam</option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function(){
                                   $("#year").change(function(){
                                       var _this = $(this);
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type :'POST',
                                            url: "", // empty string means current URL
                                            data: {year: _this.attr("value")},
                                            dataType: 'json',
                                            cache: false,
                                            error: function(e){
                                                console.log(e);
                                            },
                                            success: function(response){
                                                console.log(response);
                                            }
                                        });   
                                    });
                                });
                            </script>
```

Here is the source code:

http://www.mediafire.com/?hvv4830macfl0wm

Hope the help!

Comment: I did try `type: "POST"` but that is not working... Kindly help me to find the simplest and very basic example of using ajax with zend as I am unable to find this...

Comment: Can you do me a favour... Can you write a simple tutorial that do this effect... http://www.tradingeconomics.com/pakistan/gdp ... I shall be thankful to you.....

Comment: it gives me an error.... 

`xhr.status = 200

" Status " = parsererror Error Syntax

Error = Unexpected token I `

Comment: Actually it does not send any thing to the controller... There I got null..... in the post string...

Comment: hey, just run the source code, i tested it before uploading.
i guest that post data is empty, so try output a array by `json_encode`

Comment: Thanks for you help...... But I figure out problem.... but I don't know reason.... as jquery is not working but the dojo is working.... I don't why.....  but really appreciate and acknowledge your help... Thanks a lot again.....

Answer (score 1):

In Zend Framework you can add a `ContextSwitch` to your actions.
Based on the Context the action will render in the relevant template.

e.g.

```
    public function init()
    {
        $contextSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('contextSwitch');
        $contextSwitch->addActionContext('list', 'xml')
                      ->initContext();
    }
```

In your case

```
    $contextSwitch->addActionContext('home', 'ajax')
```

See here http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.8/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

Edit: That's for ZF1 though, if you're using ZF2 you might want to look into `View Strategy`
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#creating-and-registering-alternate-rendering-and-response-strategies